# How to load fonts in PhalconPHP with CSS in a bower package?

Tags: sass, phalcon, google-font-api

I'm trying to load the `Roboto` google font in a PhalconPHP application. I've installed `roboto-fontface` using `bower` and I'm trying to load it's fonts locally using `@font-face` in my `_fonts.scss` file.

This is my font loading "code":

```
$roboto-font-path: '../../bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts/roboto/';

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: //local(Roboto Thin),
  url("#{$roboto-font-path}Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("#{$roboto-font-path}Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff");

  font-weight: 100;
}
```

The url that I'm using seemed to work, but when inspecting what actually happens in Firefox I get the following (which is the contents of my `index.volt`):
[Screenshot of Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bckR5.png).

Of course I can load this font using `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">` but that compromises loading time when using multiple fonts in the future.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htacces` in the root of each PhalconPHP application redirects all incoming requests to the `public` directory. My `bower_components` was outside of this directory. Moved `bower_components` inside of the `public` directory using a `.bowerrc` file and modified some paths. Works like a charm now ¯_(ツ)_/¯.